# Naive bayes function in sk learn is not recognized

Tags: python

With the following code I try to load a dataset and perform a NB algorithm on it.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinominalNB 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('spambase.data.txt').as_matrix()
np.random.shuffle(data)

x = data[:, :48]
y = data[:, -1]

Ytrain = x[:-100,]
Ytrain = y[:-100,]
Xtest = x[-100:,]
Ytest = y[-100:,]

model = MultinominalNB()
model.fit(X.train, Y.train)

print "Classification rate for NB: "
```

However, when I try to run it get the following error:

```
python sample.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample.py", line 1, in <module>
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinominalNB
ImportError: No module named sklearn.naive_bayes
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

print data

Comment: Is sklearn installed on your computer? Check in a python terminal with `import sklearn`.

Comment: @Tiphaine No, if I type it I get "No module named sklearn". What should I do now? Running pip install sklearn does not work

Comment: Use `pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn` and check [installation documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried but this gives me a syntax error. Any thoughts what could be causing this?

Comment: I think you get the error because you are running the command in the python IDLE. Run it in a Terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, try:

`from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing sklearn and scikit-learn through pip.

**I fixed the issue through the following steps**

1. pip uninstall sklearn (if already installed)
2. pip uninstall scikit-learn( if already installed)
3. git clone [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git)
4. cd scikit-learn
5. python setup.py install

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please include the solution directly in your answer. Links may be useful but they do not replace proper answers. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering

Comment: Hi @MaciejJureczko , As per you request I modified the content